# Restrict Request Stream size in REST api Using Jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

How can i restrict the size of multipart-request in Jersey 2.0 RestFull api implementation?
eg. I have developed one API that accepts ("multipart/mixed") request, First Bodypart is JSON data and the second Bodypart is file, I want to restrict incoming stream to 5mb only  using some annotation or stream wrapper on the inbound http input stream.
Or is there any way to read incomming stream in parts so that i dont have to write full stream to temp file to check its size?

Comment: Have you tried just checking the Content-Length header? Usually that should be set.

Comment: Yes i did tried that and Content-Length was there but i dont want to do it in that way, iam looking for something like @MultipartConfig anotation in my Jersey REST implementation that restricts file size limit

Comment: I don't think there is anything like that that Jersey offers.You can implement it yourself in a filter using the Content-Length. See [Filters and Interceptors](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html). Aside from the filter, you can try to [set the config in the web.xml](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19145489/2587435). I don't know if it will have any affect for Jersey though. You can try it.

Comment: I did try config settings in web.xml but it did't work with jersey,may be i have to explore it more.

Comment: Also i found some performance issue when i am calling my POST method for uploading files, In backends a method  org.jvnet.MimeMessage.getAttachments() is taking around 1.7 seconds to execute which is a major performance issue,i guess jersey is internally using this method.I got this from the performance team using Dyntrace Monitoring tool.

Comment: Have you found the solution to this ?