# Unable to upload file larger than 10MB?

Tags: java, upload, jetty, restlet

Here is my code for uploading file:

```
@Override
public Representation post(Representation entity) {
    try {
        if (entity != null) {
            if (MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA.equals(entity.getMediaType(), true)) {
                DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
                factory.setSizeThreshold(100000000);
                RestletFileUpload upload = new RestletFileUpload(factory);
                FileItemIterator fileIterator = upload.getItemIterator(entity);
                while (fileIterator.hasNext()) {
                    FileItemStream item = fileIterator.next();
                    String name = item.getName();
                    byte[] byteContent  = ByteStreams.toByteArray(item.openStream());
                    if(byteContent != null) {
                        String result = doSomethingWith(byteContent);
                        Representation response = new StringRepresentation(result);
                        response.setMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
                        return response;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                return badRequest();
            }
        } else {
            return badRequest();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return internalError();
    }
    return null;
}
```

When deployed in Jetty (Java 8) it works when the file size is approximately lower then 10MB, small files like 1-2 MB, when the file is bigger like 10MB+ the upload fails randomly, what could be wrong with Restet or Jetty?

Comment: I've read about adding: ContextHandler.setMaxFormContentSize(int maxSize); for Jetty but not sure how to integrate this config with Reslet or even if it works.

Comment: What are your servlet spec multipart config settings for the servlet that handles that upload?

Comment: See prior answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19145489/775715

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fixed for this issue, was to update the max payload size of the NGINX server in front of Jetty.

Answer (score 0):

Set an attribute on the Server instance to modify maximum content size. Jetty limits the amount of data to stop DOS attacks. You can change the form upload size permission with configuration as below. [Link to documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/setting-form-size.html)

```
<configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
      <Call name="setAttribute">
      <Arg>org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormContentSize</Arg>
      <Arg>200000</Arg>
    </Call>
</configure>
```